# How to merge Date and Time using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I am new to JavaScript and don't know much. I know there are already many similar questions available but I didn't get what I was looking for.
I am having 2 inputs one is datePicker and other one is timePicker.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="a">Date :</label>
<input class="form-control" ng-model="res.Date" ng-required="true" type="date" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="a">Time :</label>
<input class="form-control timepicker" ng-model="res.Time" ng-required="true" 
type="time">
</div>
</form>
```

I am getting date and time separately and in different format -
I have converted the date in yyyy/mm/dd format and also formatted the time
using the below code -

```
 var timeString = $scope.res.Time.getHours() + ':' + $scope.res.Time.getMinutes() + ':00';
 var d = new Date($scope.res.Date),
 month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
 day = '' + d.getDate(),
 year = d.getFullYear();
 if (month.length < 2)
 month = '0' + month;
 if (day.length < 2)
 day = '0' + day;
 var fdate = [year, month, day].join('-')
```

I am getting date and time like -

```
Time = 20:42:00
Date = 2021-08-11
```

But now I want to join them and want to make it like this = **2021-08-10T01:01:55.216Z**

I tried few things like parsing but that didn't given me this format. Sorry for the mistakes.
Please Help me in getting this. Thank you

Comment: if you have Time and Date variables correct ... `${Date}T${Time}Z` - you may want to add `.000` before the `Z` though

Comment: It's good to learn how to manipulate dates by yourself. But dealing with dates is a _complicated_ matter, and there are excellent libraries that will spare you the pain of reinventing the wheel. The most famous are [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and its successor, [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon)

Comment: @JeremyThille Thank you sir, I was unaware of this before, I will try using Moment Thanks.

Comment: FYI - [You probably shouldn't use MomentJS for new projects](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let time = "20:42:00";
let date = new Date("2021-08-11");

let parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(date.toDateString() + ' ' + time));

console.log(parsedDate.toISOString());
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but sir I am getting output as "Mon Aug 16 2021 07:15:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" not like " 2021-08-10T01:01:55.216Z" this is it because you passed date and time as string ?

Comment: I updated the answer for if your input is of a date type